# How to create sql table with dynamic columns?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I am using vb 2015

I need to create sql table from a data table already been created on run time the is there a way to make it sql table ?

The other issue is that i've created a table with data table by tbl.columns.Add(ProducsATT.Name) 
ProducsATT.Name is an xml attribute which will be the table schema, i've tried to create the same with sql table but it gives an error i've used it like :

(ttbl ="CREATE TABEL Products ("

For i =0 To ProducsATT.count -1
ttbl +=  ProducsATT.Name & "VCHAR (30))"

ttbl += ")"

Next)

It gives an error on the second column. 
Is there a way to fix this ?
Rhanks all.

Comment: To start: `create table` instead of `create tabel`. Which dbms are you using? sql-server, mysql, postgres? Are you sure you need to create tables on the fly, and there isn't a better solution to your problem?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/346416)

Comment: I need to create them on the fly because there are more than 49 column in each table and afterwards the records will be inserted automatically from xml file, i am using sql server but using vb 2015 for the project.

Comment: Then `vchar(30)` should probably be `varchar(30)` and you also need to add a comma between columns.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake while i am writing the post .. Ok is there a way to create sql table from a data table ?

Comment: SqlZim has made some good suggestions, here are a few more. Your `vchar(30))` which should be `varchar(30)` needs one of the closing brackets removed. It also should have a leading space included in the string, since otherwise the field name and the data type will be next to each other. Lastly, your `Next` and `ttbl += ")"` seem to be the wrong way around. You need to iterate through the fields and then close the brackets for the create table statement.

Comment: Thanks all for your very helpful suggestions, as you said i but a leading space and moved the closing bracket after Next and it worked 